# "Device x was not an MTP device" when using usbmount

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I am trying to setup a raspberry pi to automatically copy SD card contents when it's inserted. I have managed to manually mount the cards fine using the `mount` command but `usbmount` has so far not worked at all.
At the moment I get this logged when I plug in a new device:

```
Apr 20 07:43:11 pi3testbench mtp-probe[839]: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4"
Apr 20 07:43:11 pi3testbench mtp-probe[839]: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Apr 20 07:43:11 pi3testbench mtp-probe[840]: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4"
Apr 20 07:43:11 pi3testbench mtp-probe[840]: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Apr 20 07:43:13 pi3testbench systemd-udevd[844]: sdc: Process '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add' failed with exit code 2.
Apr 20 07:43:13 pi3testbench usbmount[870]: /dev/sdd does not contain a filesystem or disklabel
Apr 20 07:43:13 pi3testbench systemd-udevd[846]: sdd: Process '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add' failed with exit code 1.
```

I can see the drive using `lsblk` fine:

```
pi@pi3testbench:~ $ lsblk -fp
NAME             FSTYPE FSVER LABEL  UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
/dev/sdb
└─/dev/sdb1      exfat  1.0
```

and as I said I can manually mount it and see the files.

(the following might be best as a second question but I'll put it here anyway)
I have previously seen `usbmount` run `mount` commands but the drive contents never appears. I tried running exactly the same mount commands and they work fine but they don't work when run by `usbmount`. This was alos with a "not an MTP device" error so perhaps this issue will be resolved when the MTP device issue is fixed.

I did try some suggestions I found such as modifying the `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` and changing the options used for different file systems but that didn't help.
I have tried several different usb sticks and SD cards from different manufacturers but they all have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> /dev/sdb1      exfat  1.0

You need to find an exfat filesystem, `$ sudo apt install exfat-fuse` will probably be suitable.

With that installed you will be able to mount the SD-card.
*It might even mount automatically as you insert it in your reader. => /media/$USER/*

Then you will be able to look into the DCIM/ folder on it to find your images.

*NOTE: MTP = Media Type Protocol, is most often used against a device over an USB cable, common amongst digital cameras nowadays(?).
Old Nikon D300's come up as a FAT device, later models e.g D700 and D850, has the MTP type connection only  (I use a card reader for the SD/CF/... -cards from these).*

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Add new details regarding this in your posting, you're not very clear on WHAT you expect to happen. If you're attempting to use an SD-card with exfat fs via "MTP" you will fail, yes. You'r `lsblk` output tells that it is an exfat formatted "disk".